# Gravity and wrong size

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

There was a problem with box2d. I wanted to add to the already existing game physics , but ran into problems. First, the game world I draw with calculation

```
public Hero(float x, float y, int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    position = new Vector2(x, y);
    velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    acceleration = new Vector2(0, -420);
}

public void update(float delta){
    velocity.mulAdd(acceleration, delta);

    if(velocity.y < -200){
        velocity.y = -200;
    }

    position.mulAdd(velocity,delta);
}

public void onTap(){
    velocity.y = 140;
}
```

the body of the hero falls from the standard setting, but the body box that I have added to the test behaves very strangely.

Question number 1. Why box2d box more than a hero with this setting, but when I divide by two, it becomes similar to the size of the texture of the hero? May be linked such effekts so that the body is drawn based on the center in all directions 2. Why is the body in the world with gravity -420 falls continuously at the same speed, but not as much as my hero. How to achieve a similar effect it?

```
    hero = new Hero(30, midPointY, 18, 21);
    hero1 = new Box2Dhero(world, 90, midPointY, 18, 21);
```

Its box2d hero constructor

```
  public Box2Dhero(World world, float x, float y, int width, int height ) {

    bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.position.set(x,y);
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

    box = new PolygonShape();
    box.setAsBox(width,height);
    fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = box;
    body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
}
```

My GameWorld size

```
 float screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
 float screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
 float gameHeight = 385;
 float gameWidth = screenWidth / (screenHeight / gameHeight);
```

Comment: Consider naming your units. Having an acceleration or gravity of 420 looks like you're using the wrong units. 420 what?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your observation about box being based on center with unit length in all directions is correct.

   It should affect your comparison in the sense that origins of box2d's box and your box do not match. This effect should be relatively small.
2. - You are clamping your velocity in y direction to -200. Making such an assumption may not be a good idea for comparison. Finding a resource regarding what does box2d do would be a good idea (source perhaps).
   - Most physics engines perform uniform time stepping to be [**deterministic**](http://www.bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Determinism). Box2D is one of them. You can read about uniform time stepping [**here**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/fixed-time-step-vs-variable-time-step).

There might be many more differences/optimizations, looking in source and comparing would be most efficient solution for you in my opinion.

Good luck.